# MVVM DataGrid Where user can add rows. Dont add until all fields are valid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF datagrid where the user can add rows. I'd like it to **not** add the new row until certain required cells are entered.

e.g.

My datagrid has the following columns, `First Name`, `Surname`, `Age`, `Job Title`, `Salary`.

When I enter a new row via the datagrid, I can just enter `First Name` and I end up with a new Model in my collection that only has `FirstName` set. I would like to not add the new Model until I have entered `FirstName`, `Surname` and `Age`.

**My Model:**

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }
    public Foo(string firstName, string surname, int age)
    {
        Age = age;
        FirstName = firstName;
        Surname = surname;
    }
    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
internal sealed class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Foo> _foos = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
    private IDataService _dataService;
    private Foo _selectedFoo;
    public RelayCommand ButtonClickCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        Foos = _dataService.Foos();
        RegisterCommands();
    }

    public void RegisterCommands()
    {
        ButtonClickCommand = new RelayCommand(
            ButtonClick,
            () => true);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos
    {
        get { return _foos; }
        set
        {
            if (_foos == value) return;
            _foos = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Foo Foo
    {
        get { return _selectedFoo; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedFoo == value) return;
            _selectedFoo = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void ButtonClick()
    {
    }
}
```

**My XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="Grid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="Main" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Foo}">
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClickCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'd like a way to do this without having an event on every cell (.e.g CellChangedEvent) if possible and keep the logic to the ViewModel. Without the ViewModel having to know anything about the View / Windows controls etc.

I've tried adding `ValidationRule`.

**ValidationRule**

```
public sealed class FooValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (((BindingGroup) value)?.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            IsValid = true;
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
        if (!(((BindingGroup) value)?.Items[0] is Foo foo))
        {
            IsValid = false;
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Error");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foo.FirstName))
        {
            IsValid = false;
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Must enter a First Name");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foo.Surname))
        {
            IsValid = false;
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Must enter a Surname");
        }
        if (foo.Age == 0)
        {
            IsValid = false;
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Must enter age");
        }

        IsValid = true;
        return new ValidationResult(true, string.Empty);
    }

    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

Now my `DataGrid` looks like this:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Foos, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Foo}">
        <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2"
                      ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
        FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" 
                             Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                             Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                               FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
        <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
            <validation:FooValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
        </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding (model:Foo.Age), ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Age" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding (model:Foo.FirstName), ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="First Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding (model:Foo.Surname), ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Surname"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding (model:Foo.JobTitle), ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Job Title"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding (model:Foo.Salary), ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Salary"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

But still, it adds a new `Foo` to the bound collection of `Foos` even if it the row is in an invalid state.

Comment: One way i have done this in the past, is to have an "Add" button that has a Dialog popup. Within this dialog you set the fields, then have a "Save"-"Cancel" button. Then you can do validation on the Save click and submit to the datagrid. AFAIK, the validation just indicates to the user whether they have input valid data, it does not control submiting the data.

Comment: I've went with having 2 lists. One list for the UI and one list that gets persisted and I'm moving stuff from the UI list to the persisted list once it's valid. Messy. I like your idea too, but it has to be entered via the datagrid unfortuntately :(

Comment: That still isnt the worst thing. Remember that your viewmodel acts as the intermediary from the view to the Model. You can have temporary or intermediary lists that sit in the ViewModel, and only on a Save type action or some trigger does that data go back to the actual Model. It isnt always pretty, but that is development :).